# Can I pass commands from host window command prompt to remote window command prompt?

Tags: command-line, remote-desktop

Can I pass commands from host window command prompt to remote window command prompt?
For example I want to open MATLAB at remote desktop without actually going there i.e. using commands from host pc only.
If its possible please post the answer, I am stuck at it for a month now!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the free
[psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec):

> PsExec is a light-weight telnet-replacement that lets you execute processes on other systems, complete with full interactivity for console applications, without having to manually install client software. PsExec's most powerful uses include launching interactive command-prompts on remote systems and remote-enabling tools like IpConfig that otherwise do not have the ability to show information about remote systems.

Examples:

The following command launches an interactive command prompt on `\\marklap`:

```
psexec -i \\marklap cmd
```

This command copies the program `test.exe` to the remote system and
executes it interactively:

```
psexec -i \\marklap -c test.exe
```